# Objective C: My UITableView doesn't see new data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have the datasource for my TableView it's very difficult with blocks and other stuff. I totally screwed it up ((( Please help me, what I am doing wrong?

My datasource code:

```
@synthesize dataItems;


+ (instancetype)sharedDataStorage
{
    static BGMDataStorage *sharedDataStorage = nil;    
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedDataStorage = [[self alloc] initPrivate];
    });

    return sharedDataStorage;
}

- (instancetype)initPrivate
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        // !!!! TEST ARRAY
        NSDictionary *preLoadDict = @{
                                      @"Val 1" : @"34",
                                      @"Val 2" : @"69",
                                      };

        dataItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:preLoadDict, nil];
    }

    return self;
}


- (void)buildDataSourcesFor:(NSString *)soapMethodName            
                     OnDate:(NSDate *)date
                 WithParams:(NSString *)param                     
             WithCompletion:(void (^)(NSString *))compblock       
                    failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure     
{
    [[BGMSbrDataProvider alloc] callWebServiceFor:soapMethodName
                                           OnDate:date
                                      WithSuccess:^(NSDictionary *resultDict) {

                                                    //success block
                                                    dataItems = [resultDict objectForKey:param];        

                                                    if (dataItems)
                                                    {
                                                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DataItemsArrayWasBuilt" 
                                                                                                                object:nil];
                                                        });
                                                    }

                                                    NSString *stringData = [self chartDataJsonStringFromArray:dataItems         
                                                                                                forMethodName:soapMethodName];

                                                    compblock(stringData);

                                                }

                                                ...


}
```

There is nothing special in UITableView code:

```
//get the number of rows
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    //return the number of rows in the section
    return [[[BGMDataStorage sharedDataStorage] dataItems] count];

}


//configure the cell
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //our cell
    //set the CellIdentifier depends on amount of columns
    NSArray *allKeys = [[[[BGMDataStorage sharedDataStorage] dataItems] objectAtIndex:0] allKeys];
    NSUInteger myUnitKeysCounter = [allKeys count];

    NSString *theCellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ListPrototypeCell%hu", (unsigned short)myUnitKeysCounter];
    DDLogVerbose(@"The current CellIdentifier is: %@.", theCellIdentifier);

    BGMDataTableViewCell *theCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:theCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //configure the cell...
    if ([theCellIdentifier isEqualToString:@"ListPrototypeCell1"])
    {

        theCell.labelText1.text = [[[[BGMDataStorage sharedDataStorage] dataItems] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:[allKeys objectAtIndex:0]];

    }
    else if ([theCellIdentifier isEqualToString:@"ListPrototypeCell2"])
    {

        theCell.labelText1.text = [[[[BGMDataStorage sharedDataStorage] dataItems] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:[allKeys objectAtIndex:0]];
        theCell.labelText2.text = [[[[BGMDataStorage sharedDataStorage] dataItems] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:[allKeys objectAtIndex:1]];

    }
```

I see in debug that I have data in dataItems when buildDataSourcesFor: but after this I see only TEST ARRAY data at uitableview. I guess maybe I lost in threads, but anyway I too far gone.
So My problem is that I see array with 24 objects at the break point in dataItems = [resultDict objectForKey:param]; and only 2 objects at return [[[BGMDataStorage sharedDataStorage] dataItems] count] after I this.

Comment: You have notification posted after successfully get data, but I don't see any code that receive notification and reload tableview.

Comment: I have it it's just ` - (void)receiveDataItemsArrayWasBuiltNotification:(NSNotification *)notification{if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"DataItemsArrayWasBuilt"]){
[self.tableView reloadData];        
    }
}` I try to put here only important part of my code because I don't want put tonnes of my code on you. And I see how it works how reloadData starts by notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not update the data source (dataItems array) before reloading the table view, The data source should be updated before calling `[tableView reloadData]`. else the old data will be loaded into the table.

Try this ,

Write this code inside `viewDidLoad` method present in your table view controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveDataItemsArrayWasBuiltNotification:) name:@"DataItemsArrayWasBuilt" object:nil];
}



- (void)receiveDataItemsArrayWasBuiltNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    //if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"DataItemsArrayWasBuilt"]){         

    [self.tableView reloadData]; 
    //}
}



 - (void)buildDataSourcesFor:(NSString *)soapMethodName            
                 OnDate:(NSDate *)date
             WithParams:(NSString *)param                     
         WithCompletion:(void (^)(NSString *))compblock       
                failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure     
{
    [[BGMSbrDataProvider alloc] callWebServiceFor:soapMethodName
                                       OnDate:date
                                  WithSuccess:^(NSDictionary *resultDict) {

                                                //success block
                                                dataItems = [resultDict objectForKey:param];        

                                                if (dataItems)
                                                {

                                                    sharedDataStorage.dataItems = dataItems;// You missed this line
                                                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DataItemsArrayWasBuilt" 
                                                                                                            object:nil];
                                                    });
                                                }

                                                NSString *stringData = [self chartDataJsonStringFromArray:dataItems         
                                                                                            forMethodName:soapMethodName];

                                                compblock(stringData);

                                            }

                                            ...
```

}

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the point... Everything fine with my notification. My problem is that I see array with 24 objects at the break point in dataItems = [resultDict objectForKey:param]; and only 2 objects at return [[[BGMDataStorage sharedDataStorage] dataItems] count] after I this.

Comment: Have you written this line(inside block), `sharedDataStorage.dataItems = dataItems;// You missed this line` check my answer and please let me know

Comment: saif hi! No I didn't write this line... I don't really understand where I should put it...

Comment: write this line and test once

Comment: Wow! Thanks saif!!! I put [BGMDataStorage sharedDataStorage].dataItems = dataItems; and it works perfect! Could you explain me why, please?

Comment: Thanks user3742622, and please mark my answer as it was helpful.